# DocumentComplete event is not fired when loading local HTML page

Tags: iwebbrowser2

I'm loading a local HTML file into IE and expecting to receive a DocumentComplete event. It's never fired. I also tried NavigateComplete and ProgressChange but they aren't fired as well. Here is the code:

```
public void OnDocumentCompleted(object pdisp, ref object url)
{
    Console.WriteLine("DocumentCompleted fired on url {0}!", url);
}

var IE = new InternetExplorer();        
object Empty = 0;

IE.NavigateComplete2 += new DWebBrowserEvents2_NavigateComplete2EventHandler(e.OnNavigateComplete2);
IE.DocumentComplete += new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(e.OnDocumentCompleted);
IE.ProgressChange += new DWebBrowserEvents2_ProgressChangeEventHandler(e.OnProgressChange);

var uri = new Uri("file://c:/iframeExample.html");
IE.Navigate(uri.AbsolutePath);

IE.Quit();
```

If I'm browsing to a page on the web, I do receive all events. So, why they are not fired for a local page?